# carthage,couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “Release-iphoneos”

Tags: ios, archive, carthage

i got a error when i archive my project. There error is that "Failed to write to /Users/cyc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rippton-dszaodulcbvgshasqsvchrhvvhpi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Rippton/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FC29EC79-AB47-37A9-B2BE-76F08DD838E6.bcsymbolmap: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“FC29EC79-AB47-37A9-B2BE-76F08DD838E6.bcsymbolmap” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “Release-iphoneos”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/cyc/Desktop/Rippton_new/Carthage/Build/iOS/FC29EC79-AB47-37A9-B2BE-76F08DD838E6.bcsymbolmap, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/cyc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rippton-dszaodulcbvgshasqsvchrhvvhpi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Rippton/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FC29EC79-AB47-37A9-B2BE-76F08DD838E6.bcsymbolmap, NSFilePath=/Users/cyc/Desktop/Rippton_new/Carthage/Build/iOS/FC29EC79-AB47-37A9-B2BE-76F08DD838E6.bcsymbolmap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f832f101260 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}}
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1".
can someOne help me?[this is my carthage's script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YwOh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, so I cleaned the project, closed any app that could be using the project, restarted xcode and then it was working again